# Why overload with param of sub class type is not chosen over some parent class

Tags: java

```
public class Imp1 implements Inter1 {
    private int num;

    @Override
    public void apply() {
        num++;
    }

    public void doubler() {
        num = num * 2;
    }

    public boolean equals(Imp1 o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Imp1))
            return false;
        return o.num == num;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Inter1 a = new Imp1();
        final Imp1 b = new Imp1();
        a.apply();
        b.apply();
        System.out.println("a equals b " + a.equals(b));
        System.out.println("b equals a " + b.equals(a));
    }

}
```

I would expect `equals(Imp1 o)` to be choosen as the best candidate for `a.equals(b)` and `b.equals(a)` why is it not the case here?

In more details - this codes outputs twice false and i am wondering why?
a and b holds Imp1 object, hence calling equals with Imp1 instance as param should invoke  `equals(Imp1 o)` which fits better than `equals(Object o)`, yet i see that `equals(Object o)` is being invoked, and finally the code prints  false twice instead of twice true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method overloading resolution is determined by the compile time type of the arguments, since the compiler chooses the best matching method signature at compile time.

`equals(Imp1 o)` can only be chosen if the compile-time type of the argument passed to the method is `Imp1` or a sub-class of `Imp1`.

`a` does not meet this criteria, so `b.equals(a)` calls `Object`'s `equals`.

As for `a.equals(b)`, since the compile time type of `a` is not `Imp1`, it can't invoke the `equals(Imp1 o)` method (unless you cast it to `Impl1`), so it can only choose `Object`'s `equals`.

```
System.out.println("a equals b " + ((Imp1)a).equals(b));
```

will call `equals(Imp1 o)`.

Comment: and what about a.equals(b)?, it prints false as well!!

Comment: but java overriding is virtual in c++ jargon, this means that the actual method needs to be invoked is that of the instance class not the reference type class

Comment: @OfekRon But in order for a method in `Imp1` to override any method in its ancestor classes, that method must match the signature of some method in these ancestor classes. The only ancestor class of `Imp1` is `Object`, and `Object` doesn't have a `equals(Imp1 o)` method.

Comment: You expect that the `equals` method implemented overrides the `equals` method in Object, but it does not.  Using `@Override` annotations can help you catch this kind of misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem is you not really override the equals of the Object super-class!!**

This is the right way to do this:

```
public class Imp1 implements Inter1 {
private int num;

@Override
public void apply() {
    num++;
}

public void doubler() {
    num = num * 2;
}

@Override//<-----need to override the equals of the superClass Object!!!
public boolean equals(Object o) {//<---must be Object!!!
    if (!(o instanceof Imp1))
        return false;
    return ((Imp1)o).num == num;
}

public int getNum() {
    return num;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Inter1 a = new Imp1();
    final Imp1 b = new Imp1();
    a.apply();
    b.apply();
    System.out.println("a equals b " + a.equals(b));
    System.out.println("b equals a " + b.equals(a));
}

}
```

OR:

```
public class Imp1 implements Inter1 {
    private int num;

    @Override
    public void apply() {
        num++;
    }

    public void doubler() {
        num = num * 2;
    }

    @Override  //<---------------need to be implemented from the interface!
    public boolean equals(Inter1 o) {//<----the class must to be from the specific interface!!! 
        if (!(o instanceof Imp1))
            return false;
        return ((Imp1)o).num == num;//<-----must to cast the object to the specific object in the "if"
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Inter1 a = new Imp1();
        final Imp1 b = new Imp1();
        a.apply();
        b.apply();
        System.out.println("a equals b " + a.equals(b));
        System.out.println("b equals a " + b.equals(a));
    }

}
```